# Is there a way to extract headers using selenium?

Tags: java, selenium

I have a test where I navigate to a site and I want to get the headers of the response.
Is there a way I can do it using selenium?

```
    URL obj = new URL(url);
    URLConnection conn = obj.openConnection();
    Map<String, List<String>> map = conn.getHeaderFields();
    for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        Log.info(String.format("key is %s and value is %s", entry.getKey(), 
        entry.getValue()));
    }
```

I tried this code but it's not working very well since i already used driver.get()

Thanks

Comment: you can use the webdriver to execute javascript to retrieve the headers.  For instance in jQuery you have jqXHR: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR

Answer (score 0):

You can [use BrowserMob-Proxy tool](https://webelement.click/en/test_server_response_headers_with_selenium_and_browsermob-proxy_in_java_automated_tests) so that:

1. You have your browser configured to use the proxy.
2. You add response filter that listens to the traffic and extracts the headers.

Since the tool is pure Java library you can start and control proxy right from your selenium test.